# Testing a Trigger that run in GOD Mode: Some field are not visible to administrator

Tags: trigger, unit-test, triggercontext

My trigger and my testMethod  uses field description:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = objectDescribe.fields.getMap();
```

### In the trigger:

i'm inserting all fields in a custom object **based on fieldsMap.**

### in the testMethod

i'm trying to verify that all inserted data (by quering my custom object) correspond to a real field **based on fieldsMap.**

### The problem

fieldsMap.get('isemailbounced') for example returns null in test method (I'm running as an admin)

> Test fails

I tried to run this code in **Execution Anonymous**

```
    Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact');
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = targetType.getDescribe();
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = objectDescribe.fields.getMap(); 
    System.debug('fieldsMap: '+ fieldsMap.get('isemailbounced'));
    sObject mySObject = targetType.newSObject();
    System.debug(mySObject.get('isemailbounced'));
```

> Anonymous execution was successful.

But if i put that code in a class or another controller i got the Exception (because i used `mySObject.get('isemailbounced')`)

> System.SObjectException: Invalid field isemailbounced for Contact

Any Suggestion?

Comment: `IsEmailBounced` was added in [Winter '14](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_api_objects.htm) so you will need to make sure that class or controller you are executing the code from is on Winter '14 (API 29) or above. The  dev console runs with the latest version so that is why its working there.

Comment: I confirm that i was running my testMethod with an older api version --> Some field were not visible. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @BarCotter, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsEmailBounced` was added in [Winter '14](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_api_objects.htm), you will need to make sure that the class or controller that is executing the code is on Winter '14 (API 29) or above. The dev console runs with the latest version so that is why it's working there.

SalesForce don't seem to be doing too well with API versioning recently. There are some known issues, see [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3FOAA0) and [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0tvAAC)

Answer (score 2):

Check your API version on your class . The Org's Dev Console upgrades by itself but the classes needs to be updated to the latest API versions . The field "IsEmailBounced" has been added in the latest Winter Release . Hence when running the code in the class , make sure you have the latest API versions for it to compile without errors. Make sure you refresh the schema in case if you are using Force.com plugin in Eclipse .